# Sony Xperia Tipo JB installation unsuccessful

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-tipo

I was trying to install JellyBean on my sony xperia tipo and have suddenly come to a halt.
I was following [this](http://www.andro-park.org/2012/12/custom-rom-update-xperia-tipo-to-cm10-jelly-bean-stable-version8091.html) tutorial.
The only thing that differed here is I obtained [the latest JB from Cyanogenmod](http://get.cm/get/76y).

I have successfully installed till the recovery image installation (CWM). Post that I tried selecting the zip which I had downloaded but the installation aborts.
Unfortunately it is not meant for tipo and I have come to a halt. I want to know what is the appropriate CM for Xperia Tipo and how do I transfer that appropriate cm_xx.zip to internal storage in the recovery mode.

Comment: Have you tried some simple [Google-Fu](http://www.google.com/search?q=cyanogenmod+%22xperia+tipo%22&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1)? Lot's of hits on the first page, e.g. [How to Update Sony Xperia Tipo with CM10 Jelly Bean](http://www.ninjaromeo.com/update-sony-xperia-tipo-cm10-jelly-bean/) and, from our friends at XDA, [Xperia Tipo ST21i OFFICIAL THREAD [ROOT, ROMS and MODS index](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1890478).

Comment: I wave gone through some of those.. But i want to know how i can transfer a file to /sdcard location in the fastboot mode if possible . @Izzy

Comment: AFAIK fastboot does not support that. Available command set in that mode is quite limited. Just enter the `fastboot` command without parameters to check for yourself: it allows to list devices, flash an image, erase or format a partition, reboot -- nothing more (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Fastboot)). So short answer: You can't do *that*.

Comment: any suggestions how to get things back to normal if the above thing is not possible? @Izzy

Comment: `fastboot flash` to directly flash an image from your PC? Besides, googling the term "fastboot" has this [Cyanogen Wiki entry](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro) as first hit. Unfortunately, they only deal with recovery there. Have you tried booting to recovery, and then using `adb push` to copy the image file to your device? According to your original post, you've successfully installed CWM, so chances are goot for that.

Comment: i tried pushing using adb, but adb says "No devices found"

Comment: If you're on Windows, this might be a driver issue, on Linux a missing entry in your *udev rules* (devices use a different ID in recovery mode). But the comments already get quite lengthy: the tipo supports microSD cards. The PC supports card readers. Put the card in a reader, copy the files to it, remove the card safely, put it into your tipo, done. Use CWM to flash. Task completed.

Comment: Appreciate the Help @Izzy

Comment: Glad you've solved it! And +1 for your answer. In two days you can "accept" it, so it's recognizable as having a "workable solution" when browsing a list of questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the question:

The problem was i couldnot find the driver for the device.Did it the manual way by selecting the Android adb interface driver.

And then used

```
adb push <local> <remote>
```

to push the file on to SdCard.

More references on the same can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) .